# Hsql - create schema if not exists in spring boot application

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, spring-boot, hsqldb

I am using embedded hsql db in my spring boot application and want to 
create a schema only if does not exist in the db.

Assuming the schema name is XXX,

I have the below single statement schema-hsql.sql file:

```
CREATE SCHEMA XXX IF NOT EXISTS
```

However this is faing with below stack trace:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/xxx/schema-hsql.sql]: CREATE SCHEMA XXX IF NOT EXISTS; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: IF

at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:494)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.runSchemaScripts(DataSourceInitializer.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.init(DataSourceInitializer.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: IF
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.execute(NewProxyStatement.java:909)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:473)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unexpected token: IF
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.parseError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.unexpectedToken(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.getCompiledStatementBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileCreateSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileCreate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 81 more
```

What is the correct syntax for achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

use

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS XXX
```

instead of your sql

```
CREATE SCHEMA XXX IF NOT EXISTS
```

and use org.hsqldb::hsqldb v.2.4.0

See:
[Hsql - create schema if not exists in spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37963370/hsql-create-schema-if-not-exists-in-spring-boot-application?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify this in your `hibernate.cfg.xml" as following :

```
<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Here's full example :

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:file:db/personh2db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE</property>
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="connection.password"/>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <mapping resource="com/example/model/Person.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
```

The list of possible options for `hbm2ddl.auto`are,

- **validate**: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
- **update**: update the schema.
- **create**: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
- **create-drop**: drop the schema at the end of the session.

### EDIT

You can configure hibernate properties in `application.properties` when you're using Spring boot.

Here's the documentation for `application.properties` : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

You can find an example for `hbm2ddl.auto` configuration here : http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties

Comment: I do not have hibernate.cfg.xml sinnce I am running on spring boot. I guess my problem is CREATE SCHEMA XXX IF NOT EXISTS statement is somewhat wrong and I am searchıng the correct versıon for hsql db.