# Microsoft SQL server auto create schema if not exists on spring boot (application.properties)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I could not find how to tell spring boot to create schema if it does not exist on ms SQL, for example, in MySQL, I was able to achieve this goal by doing this:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

This is the code for MS SQL:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Example
ofcurse with email and password confioration...

```
Hibernate Configuration:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

I tried to look over the internet and here but could not find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the EDIT section of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37964359/12357638) on SO.

In particular, note the links to Spring Boot's [application.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html) file, and the [database initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-database-initialization) section of the Spring Boot reference docs.

Also see the Hibernate documentation for [Automatic schema generation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl), which tells you what the options to `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` mean.

Comment: I could not find the right configuration for ms Sql on one of your links

Comment: The Hibernate configuration is independent of database type.